# Programmatically create grouped products in Magento 2

Tags: product, magento2

Is it possible to create grouped products in Magento2 programmatically?
There are examples for Magento1 but not for Magento2.

Could you provide some examples?

Answer (score 5):

You can create links int grouped like any other kind of link. The example below shows the product link factory injected into the class and then used to create a set of grouped association links. It is the use of the link type 'associated' that makes the links associations between the grouped product and its contained products:

```
protected $productLinkFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductLink\LinkFactory $productLinkFactory
) {
    $this->productLinkFactory = $productLinkFactory;
}

function addLinksToProduct(array $links, $product) {
    $links = array();

    foreach ($linkData as $linkData) {
        $link = $this->productLinkFactory->create()
            ->setSku($linkData['source_sku'])
            ->setLinkedProductSku($linkData['dest_sku'])
            ->setPosition($linkData['position'])
            ->setLinkType('associated');
        $link
            ->getExtensionAttributes()
            ->setQty($linkData['qty']);
        $links[] = $link;
    }
    $product->setProductLinks($links);

    $product->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I m new with Magento 2 so correct me if I m wrong.
The file responsible for grouped products is */module-grouped-product/Model/Product/Initialization/Helper/ProductLinks/Plugin/Grouped.php*
In Magento 2 we use a plugin to add the related products.

Let's suppose you have the product like this:

```
$product->setTypeId('grouped')
->setName('My Grouped product')
->setSku('my-grouped-sku')
```

..
..
..whatever else you need to set for your product which is similar to making a simple product.

```
    $links = $this->getLinksForGrouped($childrenIds,$groupedProductSku);

    $product->setProductLinks($links); //This is what you need.
                    $product->save();



    public function getLinksForGrouped($childrenIds,$groupedProductSku){
            $associated = array();
            $position = 0;
            foreach($childrenIds as $productId){
                $position++;
//You load each product to get what you need in order to build $productLink
                $linkedProduct = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
                /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterface $productLink */
                $productLink = $this->productLinkFactory->create();

                $productLink->setSku($groupedProductSku)
                    ->setLinkType('associated')
                    ->setLinkedProductSku($linkedProduct->getSku())
                    ->setLinkedProductType($linkedProduct->getTypeId())
                    ->setPosition($position)
                    ->getExtensionAttributes()
                    ->setQty(0);

                $associated[] = $productLink;

            }

            return $associated;

        }
```

Have a look inside that file in order to call the right classes in your constructor for productLinkFactory,productRepository.